# Does PEB store the process that already terminated?

Tags: c++, process

PEB store the information of a process in windows.
Does it still stored it when a process has ended ?

Answer (score 2):

It is an in-process data structure.  No more process == no more PEB.

The process handle returned by CreateProcess references a kernel data structure, it will stay around as long as you don't close the handle, even after the process terminated.  Calling WaitForSingleObject() on that handle tells you when the process exits.  GetExitProcessCode() tells you how it exited.

Answer (score 0):

No, PEB hold only information about currently running processes. You can read more about PEB here:http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_Environment_Block

AFAIK there is no such block in Windows OS which holds data for terminated processes

Comment: Is there a way to capture information of a short process (this process just run in 0.01 second) ? WMI can not poll this because it's too fast

Comment: You should hook process creation, here is a very good example of doing this: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11985/Hooking-the-native-API-and-controlling-process-cre When you hook process creation you can get information of EVERY process being created even if they run for a really short time